# How can I get all media from my own Instagram api?

Tags: python, instagram-api

I want to get number of likes each photo or video got. Can I get all the media like count or just the last 20 of them?

Comment: I have read the new policy. I just wanted to make sure if there is anyway for the owners of the account to get the data. I thought it might affect third parties not the owner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get your API access reviewed and approved by Instagram you will be able to get more than 20 photos using pagination.

Check documentation here: https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/

Comment: Thanks, I thought maybe there is a way for owners of the accounts to get their photos and this review is just for third parties.

Comment: then u can use a 3rd party service like https://www.picodash.com or u can also use instagram.com to access all photos